# How to pass a dynamic url to a function through onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui

I needs a hep on this, i was trying to pass a dynamic url to a function.

code

```
onload="getImage('+ val.logo +');" onclick="loadPageMerchantInfo('+ val.merchant_id +');
```

val.logo holds a url like this : https://www.example.com/upload/default-food-image.png

i needs to pass this url to a function below

```
function getImage(url)
{
setStorage("merchant_logo",url);
var logo = getStorage("merchant_logo");
onsenAlert(logo);
return logo;
}

function loadPageMerchantInfo(str)
{

var merlogos = getImage();
onsenAlert(merlogos);
setStorage("merchant_id",str);


var options = {
  animation: 'none',
  onTransitionEnd: function() {                   
      displayMerchantLogo2( 
             merlogos,
             '' ,
             'page-merchantinfo'
      );                  
      callAjax("getMerchantInfo","merchant_id="+ getStorage('merchant_id'));              
  } 
};  
sNavigator.pushPage("merchantInfo.html", options);     
merhantPopOverMenu.hide(); 
}
```

So when i print the value there is nothing, just showing " undefined".

Comment: onload="getImage('+ val.logo +');" onclick="loadPageMerchantInfo('+ val.merchant_id +');  should be  onload="getImage(val.logo);" onclick="loadPageMerchantInfo(val.merchant_id);  because you can't insert strings like that into functions.

Comment: htm+='<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" class="list-item-container" onload="getImage('+ val.logo +');" onclick="loadPageMerchantInfo('+ val.merchant_id +');" >';

Answer (score 0):

Inside the html:

```
onload="getImage(val.logo);";
```

Inside of js:

```
window.onload=()=>getImage(val.logo);
window.onclick=()=>loadPageMerchantInfo(val.merchant_id);
```

You may have a look at arrow functions ( normal ones are also fine ) and closures.

Why your code doesnt work:

```
window.onload="a string";
//the js engine does:
window.onload();
//wich will cause an error:
ERROR: window.onload is not a function!
```

If you really want this bad styled string thing, you need to convert the String into a Function:

```
onload=new Function("getImage("+ val.logo +");");
onclick=new Function("loadPageMerchantInfo("+ val.merchant_id +");");
```

However, every JSlover will kill you for that.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I am using a a API and       htm+='<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" class="list-item-container" onload="getImage('+ val.logo +');" onclick="loadPageMerchantInfo('+ val.merchant_id +');" >';      without using the '"+" i cannot get the value.  By using the above code i am getting the value of +val.merchant_id+.  but i am not getting the value of +val.logo+, since val.logo contains a url.

Comment: @stalinstephen i think you should have a deeper look into js. we already gave you the necessary answers...

Comment: brother i understand you .. Let me add: Its a Phonegap app